# Is it necessary to update Windows 10 build?

Tags: windows-10-preview

I still use windows 10 build 9841, because when I update to a new build I lose performance and Windows takes much more time to load programs.

I still receive updates through Windows updates, do I have to update to a new build?

Comment: The update isn't the cause of your performance; you do understand its not meant to be your actual os right?

Comment: the performance lose happens even when i use windows 8 repair ability. clean installations always give me better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get any new updates for Build 9841. You have to update to Build 9860 and next Build 9879 (via Fast Ring option) to be up to date.